# Best way to approach Measurements with different UnitTypes

Tags: ios, swift, units-of-measurement

### Context:

I am writing an app where I want to display the nutritional facts of each menu item.
I wanted to have the flexibility of converting using the Measurement class.

### Problem:

The problem is that calories is measured in Measurement < UnitEnergy > , while other properties like proteins are measured in Measurement < UnitMass > . I decided to make the variable of type Measurement < Unit >  so it could handle both types. But then I loose all possibility to do conversions or operations with the variable.

This function would give me Error (which makes sense, I just don't know what would be the best way to approach this)

> Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'Measurement < Unit > '
>   operands

```
func getPercentage() -> Double {
     return value / property.referenceIntake
}
```

If I try to cast it I get this error

> Cast from 'Measurement < Unit > ' to unrelated type
>   'Measurement < UnitMass > ' always fails

```
if let massUnitMeasurement = value as? Measurement<UnitMass>, let referenceMeasurement = property.referenceIntake as? {
....
}
```

### What I have so far:

```
struct NutritionInformation {
    let property: NutritionProperties
    let value: Measurement<Unit>

    var formattedValue: String {
        let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        formatter.unitStyle = .medium
        formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
        return formatter.string(from: value)
    }
}

enum NutritionProperties {
    case calories
    case carbohydrate
    case cholesterol
    case fat
    case saturatedFat
    case fibre
    case protein
    case sodium
    case sugar

    var unit: Unit {
        switch self {
            case .calories: return UnitEnergy.kilocalories
            case .cholesterol, .sodium: return UnitMass.milligrams
            default: return UnitMass.grams
        }
    }

    var referenceIntake: Measurement<Unit> {
        switch self {
            case .calories: return Measurement(value: 2000, unit: unit)
            case .fat: return Measurement(value: 70, unit: unit)
            case .saturatedFat: return Measurement(value: 20, unit: unit)
            case .carbohydrate: return Measurement(value: 260, unit: unit)
            case .fibre: return Measurement(value: 30, unit: unit)
            case .sugar: return Measurement(value: 90, unit: unit)
            case .protein: return Measurement(value: 50, unit: unit)
            case .sodium: return Measurement(value: 2300, unit: unit)
            case .cholesterol: return Measurement(value: 300, unit: unit)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make calories a separate  property. What would be the equivalent UnitMass.grams for UnitEnergy.kilocalories?

Comment: I'd have to suggest you're sort of looking in the wrong place; "I want to display" means you need MeasurementFormatters here. Do not maintain values (data) as Measurement objects; maintain them as numbers and use Measurement-plus-MeasurementFormatter to display them.

Comment: @matt formattedValue already uses MeasurementFormatter

Comment: Why don't you get the `.value` on the measurements?

Comment: @LeoDabus the thing is that I would never mix UnitMass.grams with UnitEnergy.kilocalories, that's why I also tried to cast them. Maybe I will have to make some variables separated, but it doesn't look clean. I don't really get it because UnitMass and UnitEnergy inherit from Unit right?

Comment: If you would never mix them it doesn't make sense what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Sulthan maybe that's the only solution... but I wanted to have the flexibility of being able to convert from different units.
For example the restaurant gives me the nutrition in kilograms, and I have to compare it with the daily recommended intake that it's in grams

Comment: @PMT it would be easy to store them all as grams

Comment: @PMT Why don't you limit units to the ones inheriting from `Dimension`? Then you can convert any value to `baseUnitValue`.

Comment: So what do you recommend:
A- I remove the calories and put it as a different variable
B- I remove Measurement completely and just handle all units myself, trying to make it standarize (eg everything in grams)

Comment: @Sulthan but UnitMass and UnitEnergy are already part of Dimension, right?
I don't understand why I can't cast them. How do you use exactly the baseUnitValue?

Comment: @PMT I think something like `measurement.unit.unitConverter.baseUnitValue(from: measurement.value)`, if it's a `Dimension` unit.

Answer (score 0):

At the end what I did was to cast the Dimension itself to UnitMass or UnitEnergy (instead of casting Measurement < Dimension > to Measurement < UnitMass >), and then creating a new Measurement with the casted value.

```
var percentage: Double {
        if let referenceAsMass = property.unit as? UnitMass, let valueAsMass = value.unit as? UnitMass {
            let valueMeasurement = Measurement(value: value.value, unit: valueAsMass)
            let referenceMeasurement = Measurement(value: property.referenceIntake.value, unit: referenceAsMass)
            return valueMeasurement.converted(to: .grams).value / referenceMeasurement.converted(to: .grams).value
        }
        if let referenceAsEnergy = property.unit as? UnitEnergy, let valueAsEnergy = value.unit as? UnitEnergy {
            let valueMeasurement = Measurement(value: value.value, unit: valueAsEnergy)
            let referenceMeasurement = Measurement(value: property.referenceIntake.value, unit: referenceAsEnergy)
            return valueMeasurement.converted(to: .calories).value / referenceMeasurement.converted(to: .calories).value
        }
        return value.value / property.referenceIntake.value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PMTs solution is pretty much the only way to do it.

You can't cast a `Measurement<Unit>` to a `Measurement<UnitLength>`, or a UnitArea, etc...

They are completely different types.

But when a `Measurement<UnitLength>` is cast to `Measurement<Unit>` it does still retain its value and unit type information. So you can recreate the measurement of the correct type.

Heres an example generic function that takes an array of Measurement and returns the first result that has Unit of type T:

```swift
import Foundation

let length = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.meters) as Measurement<Unit>
let area = Measurement(value: 15, unit: UnitArea.squareMeters) as Measurement<Unit>
let time = Measurement(value: 22, unit: UnitDuration.seconds) as Measurement<Unit>
let temp = Measurement(value: 30, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius) as Measurement<Unit>

var measurements = [
    area,
    time,
    length,
    temp
] as [Measurement<Unit>]

func getMeasurement<T: Unit>(ofType: T.Type, from measurements: [Measurement<Unit>]) -> Measurement<T>? {
    let firstMeasurementsOfSameType: Measurement<T>? = measurements.compactMap {
        guard let unit = $0.unit as? T else { return nil }
        return Measurement(value: $0.value, unit: unit)
    }.first
    
    return firstMeasurementsOfSameType
}

let measurement = getMeasurement(ofType: UnitLength.self, from: measurements) 

print(String(describing: measurement)) // Prints Optional(10.0 m)
```