# How to downcast Measurement<Unit> to subclass

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Im trying to figure out the best way to downcast from a Measurement to something more specific, for example:

```
var thing = Measurement(value: 24, unit: UnitLength.meters) as Measurement<Dimension>
var thing2 = thing as! Measurement<UnitLength>
```

This will crash and Xcode will give a warning that:

> Cast from `Measurement<Dimension>` to unrelated type
> `Measurement<UnitLength>` always fails

I've found [this stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60644297/best-way-to-approach-measurements-with-different-unittypes) that suggests creating a new object like this:

```
let thing3 = Measurement(value: thing.value, unit: UnitLength.meters)
```

but that seems hacky and doesnt scale well if I wanted to return a generic Measurement, I would have to switch over every type everywhere I want to use it to create the object.

Comment: Well, your opening line is silly. What is the `as` part for? A measurement in UnitLength is a UnitLength measurement.

Comment: How did you even end up in this situation? Why do you have a `Measurement<Dimension>` in the first place?

Comment: Generics of different types are not related, even if the encapsulated types are related.  You can't use downcast as the error says. You need to create a new object of the required generic type.

Comment: @matt the as part is just a demonstration, If I had an array of different Measurement<Unit> types, I have no way to down cast them to their specific types

Comment: @sweeper I just mentioned it, but I was hoping to store measurements in an array and down cast them to compare

Comment: Well that's what I'm not understanding. There is nothing to cast down. If you have different unit lengths you can just convert. If you want to change a UnitLength to a UnitMass that makes no sense and the universe will explode.

Comment: But you can't store apples and oranges in the same array. This is Swift. `Measurement<UnitLength>` is a type. `Measurement<UnitMass>` is a totally unrelated type. You can't put them together.

Comment: @Paulw11 Is that the only solution? So it would be impossible to store these all as Measurement<Unit> or Measurement<Dimension> and have them actually be useful?

Comment: `Dimension` is an abstract type.  If you had an array of measurements using `Dimension` how would you even know what to downcast *to*?  If you know they are lengths, store them as lengths

Comment: @matt That's fair, I was hoping to simplify things by treating everything as a "Measurement" and checking their type to see if they're relevant to the type im comparing them to. I guess that's not what the class is meant for.

Comment: It's not a matter of "fair" or "class". It's what a generic is.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've done it using the example above by checking the unit type. if the unit is of type UnitLength then I can create a new object like that

Comment: @matt When I say "that's fair" I'm referring to what you said. its a valid point that I didnt consider. And the measurement is a class, with a Unit, but the unit is concrete and allows for subclassing, so that's why I dont understand why you couldn't cast if the type is a subclass

Comment: Well, you can store an array of `Any` and use a `switch/case let` to attempt conditional downcast to your possible types, but it seems like you have a fundamental problem in your model. You shouldn't really have an array of unknown measurement types any more than you would have an array of items that could be strings or ints or floats.  If an item could have a mass or a length or a temperature, it should have three optional properties of the appropriate type.

Comment: @Paulw11 That's a good point. I didnt think of it that way, and I was able to get things working with `Any` but doesn't really save me anything. I think I'll end up changing the structure to treat each value independently since that seems to be the pattern. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As Matt and I explained specialisations of a generic are not related classes even if their specialisations are related.

Comment: I'm cautious to join this comment chain, I don't want OP to feel piled-on, but Vincent, you should consider posting your code to codereview.stackexchange.com . I say this because the very notion of having a heterogeneous array of miscellaneous measurements seems so bizarre to me, that I suspect there's something very odd going on behind-the-scenes. Addressing that might really help you simplify things.

Comment: It seems that the basic misunderstanding here is demonstrated by the use of words like "downcast" and "subclass" in the title. There are no subclasses in this story! Hence there is nothing to downcast from or to — and that is exactly what the compiler tells you.

Comment: @Alexander I agree, it does seem a little strange which is why I understand people's confusion. I can't really post the code (company policy and there's a long chain of things above it in the code) But I'll try to simplify it a little and post a snippet if I can. Appreciate the response!

Comment: @matt I understand that, but in the end they are all concrete `Measurement` structs (Yes, you can instantiate it from measurement) and UnitLength is a subclass of Unit->Dimension->UnitLength. So I guess the problem im encountering is that I am trying to downcast Measurement rather than the property inside of it

Answer (score 1):

The basic misunderstanding here is demonstrated by the use of words like "downcast" and "subclass" in the title. There are no subclasses in this story! Hence there is nothing to downcast from or to — and that is exactly what the compiler tells you.

It seems, therefore, as if you're not understanding what a generic *is*. The overall generic is not itself a type. A particular specification of the generic is a type, but the types that you get from different particular specifications are unrelated to one another.

So, `Measurement<UnitLength>` is a type. `Measurement` is not a type at all, and `Measurement<Dimension>` and `Measurement<UnitMass>` are completely unrelated types.